# Dns.GetHostEntryAsync(host) Name or service not known (.Net Core - Docker)

Tags: linux, docker, .net-core

I am deploying a .NET Core 3.1 application in a Docker Linux container. In the application I use a function to obtain the host using an IP:

```
await Dns.GetHostEntryAsync(host)
```

where "host" is a IPv4.

Checking the container log, executing that function throws an exception:

```
System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByAddress(IPAddress address)
at System.Net.Dns.ResolveCallback(Object context)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Net.Dns.HostResolutionEndHelper(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Dns.EndGetHostEntry(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
```

Do I need to do any configuration in the container, or in the application?

Thank you for your answers.